# Fingerprint deletes itself on Dell XPS 13 plus - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: authentication

My fingerprint firmware is ok since I can enroll new fingerprints:

```
sudo fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-retry-scan
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-remove-and-retry
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-remove-and-retry
Enroll result: enroll-remove-and-retry
Enroll result: enroll-remove-and-retry
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-completed
```

Now - it should be there and it is when using fprintd-list user.

After I do sudo apt install libpam-fprintd, it asks for a fingerprint. However, it is not matched and THEN this happens:

```
Aug 13 11:26:13 xxx fprintd[5433]: Deleted stored finger 7 for user xxx as it is unknown to device.
```

Then, it's removed from the fprintd-list as well.

Environment:

```
fprintd/jammy,now 1.94.2-1 amd64 [installed]
libfprint-2-2:amd64 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.01 amd64 async fingerprint library of fprint project, shared libraries
libfprint-2-tod1:amd64 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.01 amd64 async fingerprint library of fprint project, drivers shared libraries
libfprint-2-tod1-goodix 0.0.6-0ubuntu1~somerville1 amd64 Goodix driver module for libfprint-2 Touch OEM Driver
```

Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic
DELL XPS 13
I use I3, however GDM is the desktop manager. I have tried KDE, LightDM and GDM. I've tried both solutions from Gnome and KDE to enroll fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on my brand new XPS 13 Plus (9320) (but in Pop!_OS). My "solution" was to clear all fingerprints from the module using a user-provided appimage. Then enroll two fingerprints in the standard way. You will still see one of the prints removed on first use, but it will remain stored in the sensor and, because the system still sees the other fingerprint enrolled, it will still offer the option to unlock with fingerprint. You can see my [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/woi1w5/xps_13_plus_9320_fingerprint/) for details and an explanation of the full journey.